# Вернуть пустую функцию

Tags: c

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void instruction(void);

main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

  printf(" - ", instruction());

  system("PAUSE");
}

void instruction(void)
{
printf("что-то здесь написано");
return;
}
```

Я хочу вернуть эту фразу, как мне это сделать, я не понимаю, как передавать функции с пустым значением, или с текстом. Можете подсказать как это работает? Как функция может передать допустим просто вывод на экран сообщение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наверно так если я вопрос правильно понял:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void instruction(void);

main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

  //printf(" - ", instruction());
  instruction();

  system("PAUSE");
}

void instruction(void)
{
printf("что-то здесь написано");
return;
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо, а вот слово return если не указывать или указывать. играет роль в целом, пробовал результат не меняется?

Comment: без разницы, как душе угодно. это дело привычки. да и еще: если значения в функцию не передаются можно писать пустые скобки например: void instruction(void); и void instruction(); - это одно и тоже

Comment: Спасибо буду знать.

Comment: Эээ... Не совсем так. В C (в отличие от C++)

    void instruction();

означает, что в функцию могут быть переданы _любые_ параметры, и компилятор не будет проверять из типы. Декларация

    void instruction(void);

означает, что функция не принимает никаких параметров.

Comment: @VladD >> означает, что в функцию могут быть переданы любые параметры. а разве это делается не так `void instruction(...);`?

Comment: @perfect: http://ideone.com/uY85G9

Comment: интересная фича

Comment: @perfect: это фича C, в C++ вам нужно `...`.

Comment: но ведь компилятор с++ компилит и сишные коды

Comment: @perfect: да, но следует при этом стандарту C.

---
@avp: наверное, имеется в виду gcc, в котором как бы одна и та же команда компиляции используется как для `.cpp`, так и для `.c`.

Comment: @perfect, я бы все таки сказал, что компилятор С++ компилит исключительно крестовые коды.

Просто многие сишные коды совпадают с крестовыми.